How get Last updated date from nuget package version
I'm trying to use the NuGet.Protocol library to get information about the version of the Nuget package. In particular, I am interested in the date of the last update of the package version.
I get the data as follows:
var sourcesRepository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
var packageMetadataResources = await sourcesRepository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();
// Получение метаданных пакета по названию.
var packageMetadata = await packageMetadataResources.GetMetadataAsync(packName, true, false, new SourceCacheContext(), NullLogger.Instance, CancellationToken.None);
// Получение метаданных последнего пакета.
var lastVersion = packageMetadata.OrderByDescending(x => x.Identity.Version).FirstOrDefault();

I looked through all the properties of the package, but did not find any data on the latest version update date...
